# Spring-Data-JPA throws "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'." by using findAll

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was searching google for 2 days now but I am not able find an suitable answer for my problem :-).

I'm trying to use the Spring Data JPA Repositories `findAll()` function to use pagination.

I am using Spring-Data-JPA in Version "1.7.1.RELEASE".
The Backend SQL is a MS-SQL 2008 server and I am using JTDS in version "1.3.1".

I have created an JPA Entity and querying the database using e.g the `findOne` method works fine and gives me the expected answer but when I use the `findAll(Pageable arg0)` method the following stacktrace was thrown:

```
        2015-01-26 12:23:49,527 DEBUG | could not extract ResultSet [n/a] 
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:459) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:357) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:326) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442) [spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427) [spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381) [spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122) [spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.findAll(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.findAll(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.X.Y.Z.main(GenericAccountCompare_Analyse.java:51) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293) [exec-maven-plugin-1.3.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
2015-01-26 12:23:49,528  WARN | SQL Error: 102, SQLState: 42000 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,528 ERROR | Incorrect syntax near 'limit'. 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,529 DEBUG | Mark transaction for rollback 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,531 DEBUG | rolling back 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,559 DEBUG | rolled JDBC Connection 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,559 DEBUG | re-enabling autocommit 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,588 DEBUG | Releasing JDBC connection 
2015-01-26 12:23:49,588 DEBUG | Released JDBC connection
```

My VendorAdapterConfig looks like

```
<bean id="jpaVendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
</bean>
```

Here is the code block using the findAll method (line 51 as stated in the stacktrace):

```
Page<Workrelationship> wrPage = wrRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 20));
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks and kind regards

Shelltux

PS: I also tested it with using the MS-JDBC driver with the same error

**[Update]**

Here is the generated query:

```
select workrelati0_.a as aR1_9_, workrelati0_.b as b2_9_, workrelati0_.c as c6_9_, workrelati0_.d as d7_9_, workrelati0_.e as e3_9_, workrelati0_.f as f4_9_, workrelati0_.g as gO5_9_ from tblWorkRelationship workrelati0_ limit ?
```

If I execute that query directly using the MS-SQL Studio I am receiving the same error
    Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

I have no persistence.xml or any other hibernate configuration. All is done using Spring-Data Configbeans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.c3p0.pool.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.c3p0.pool.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.c3p0.pool.maxPoolSize}" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.X.Y.Z.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="myEmf" 
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="base" />
        <qualifier value="my-db" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendor" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.X.Y.Z.domain" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="base" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**[/Update]**

**[Update2]**

I tested the dialects using the supportsLimit-Function with an unexpected outcome.
As stated above I am using an MS-SQL 2008 server and the limit-Function is supported starting with MS-SQL 2012.

SQLServerDialect, as well as SQLServer2005Dialect and as well as SQLServer2008Dialect returns true by calling supportLimit.

```
SQLServerDialect dialect = new SQLServerDialect();
log.info("Support limit: " + dialect.supportsLimit());

SQLServer2005Dialect dialect2005 = new SQLServer2005Dialect();
log.info("Support limit: " + dialect2005.supportsLimit());

SQLServer2008Dialect dialect2008 = new SQLServer2008Dialect();
log.info("Support limit: " + dialect2008.supportsLimit());

2015-01-26 13:52:38,594  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect 
2015-01-26 13:52:38,596  INFO | Support limit: true 
2015-01-26 13:52:38,597  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect 
2015-01-26 13:52:38,597  INFO | Support limit: true 
2015-01-26 13:52:38,598  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect 
2015-01-26 13:52:38,599  INFO | Support limit: true
```

**[/Update2]**

**[Update3]**

Here is the output including getLimitString:

```
2015-01-26 14:25:14,815  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,817  INFO | Support limit: true 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,817  INFO | Limit-String: select top 20 * from A 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,817  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,818  INFO | Support limit: true 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,818  INFO | Limit-String: select top 20 * from A 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,818  INFO | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,819  INFO | Support limit: true 
2015-01-26 14:25:14,820  INFO | Limit-String: select top 20 * from A
```

Look correct to me :-).

**[/Update3]**

Comment: Remove the setting of the `database` property as that overrides the `databasePlatform` one and sets the dialect to `SQLServerDialect`. Use one or the other not both.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I deleted the "database" property but the error still remains.

Comment: Can you add the generated query? Do you have a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `persistence.xml` file? If so please add that to your question.

Comment: looks like it isn't using the correct dialect... Make sure you don't have any additional configuration which can override the dialect.

Comment: I thought it is definitely a bug, considering your test results, but then I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.html#supportsLimit()). `supportsLimit()` returns `true` if some form of LIMIT is supported. Previous versions supported `select top 1 from ...` syntax, so `true` is ok. You should check the output of `getLimitString()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comments.
I found the error :-)

It was my fault.
I am using two Transaction-Managers with JPA. One for the application backend SQL and one for an embedded database.
So I had to configure two Spring HibernateJpaVendorAdapter Beans and the fault was that I gave both the same name so the one for the application backend was overwritten by the one for the embedded database.

Thanks and regards

Shelltux

Comment: Any code/snippet where you make correction for this?

Answer (score 2):

I too was using 2 entity managers but I had copied and pasted the database dialect of one (MySQL) to the other (SQLServer) and had the same issue.  This post was great because I checked my database dialect and sure enough it was incorrect.  Once corrected, it worked!

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:
This resolved the issue for me:

in the application.yml:

```
datasources:
    thisIsTheDatasourceName:
         dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```